# testing android apps on real devices

Tags: android, testing, user-interface

I have a samsung s6102 and s9100 and some applications I'm working on. The problem is that I'll like to test my app on real devices and I was thinking we can do something togheter. anyone who has a question aboiut how his apps works on my devices, I'm open to test. also I'll like to know how my application acts on your devices.

Maybe this type of services is already available, but I didn't find it.

Any idea about how can I test my app on real devices, without buying them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Samsung offers such a [service](http://developer.samsung.com/remoteTestLab.do).

However, there are quite a bit of limitations to that. Your best bet would be to either buy a few devices that cover the majority of features. I personally have 5 Android devices which cover various hardware specifications and screen densities. Additionally, if you have friends with Android devices, you could see if they are open to having you test your app on them. You could also hold private betas with other developers you might meet in chat rooms or on forums.

Also, if you do buy devices, make sure that you buy from more than one manufacturer, and that some devices are low end, some high end, some mid ranged, some big, some small. Also, I'd recommend buying at least one Nexus device.

Comment: can you name such chat rooms or forums. if naming them is against some SO rules, please send me an email to dole.doug@yahoo.com .many thanks